# JPQL SELECT ElementCollection

Tags: select, jpql, java-ee-7

I have an entity "Post" with this property:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name ="tags")
private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then i have a native select query with a group by. The problem is now how can i select the property tags?

My select query:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p.id,MAX(p.createdAt),MAX(p.value) FROM Post p JOIN p.tags t WHERE t IN (?1,?2,?3) GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY COUNT(p) DESC");
    /* ...

    query.setFirstResult(startIndex);
    query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();

    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object[] result : results) {
        Post newPost = new Post();
        newPost.setId(((Number) result[0]).longValue());
        newPost.setCreatedAt((Date) result[1]);
        newPost.setValue((String) result[2]);
        posts.add(newPost);
    }
    return posts;
```

how to select the property tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if it will help, but in JPA2.1 Spec, part *4.4.6 Collection Member Declarations*, you can do that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o
FROM Order o, IN(o.lineItems) l
WHERE l.product.productType = ‘office_supplies’
```

So I guess with your case, you could try:

```
SELECT p.id,MAX(p.createdAt),MAX(p.value), t
FROM Post p, IN(p.tags) t 
WHERE t IN (?1,?2,?3) 
GROUP BY p.id, t
ORDER BY COUNT(p) DESC
```

Note: I added t to the `GROUP BY`, since it would not work with the query without using an aggregate function.

Comment: thank you but now i get for each tag the same entity because of the group by t. i want to select t as a List<String>. is this possible?

Comment: In fact, after rereading your query, I don't understand why you're doing a MAX out of p.createDate, p.value while you group by p.id which is probably a primary key => remove the group by and use lazy (or eager) loading, eg: `for (Post post : results) post.getTags();`

Comment: i just solved the problem as i now select only p insted of all its attributes.